# Is this function $f:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ onto?

Tags: functions, proof-explanation

Let $f: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ be defined by
$$(m,n)\mapsto (2m+n, 3m+5n).$$
Is $f$ injective and surjective?

Comment: I have proved injection. But can't quite figure out if the function is surjective. The inverse matrix of the function is fractional so I think it should not be an onto function. But I find that unconvincing.

Comment: If $(2m + n, 3m + 5n) = (a,b)$ can you always find some $m,n$ where that will be true?  Will that $m,n$ be unique.

Comment: @fleablood What would map to (1,1)?

Comment: The matrix corresponding to the transformation has $\det A = 7$ so injectivity follows.

Comment: Yes. I have proved that it is one-to-one. But is it onto as well?

Comment: I asked you.  Does anything?  If not what does that say about injection, surjection.  If you can, can you map for everything else.

Comment: @chittychitty What would map to (1,1)?

Comment: If there is a solution in the integers it will be a solution in the reals. So, if the inverse (in the reals) is not integral, then that  point cannot be in the range.

Comment: "The inverse matrix of the function is fractional so I think it should not be an onto function. But I find that unconvincing."  Are there any integers $(a,b)$ so that if $2m+n = a$ and $3m+5 = b$ would mean that $m$ and $n$ can not both but integers?  Would that be more convincing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For surjectivity, we want to know if given $(k_1, k_2) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ we can find $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $(2m + n, 3m + 5n) = (k_1, k_2)$. We have the system of equations
$$\begin{array}{c} 2m + n &=& k_1 \\ 3m + 5n &=& k_2\end{array} $$
We can rewrite this as the matrix
$$\left[\begin{array}{c c c c} 2 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 3 & 5 & 0 & -1\end{array}\right]$$
Row reducing this yields
$$\left[\begin{array}{c c c c} 7 & 0 & -5 & 1 \\ 0 & 7 & 3 & -2 \end{array}\right]$$
This means that 
$$\begin{array}{c} 7m - 5k_1 + k_2 &=& 0 \\ 7n + 3k_1 - 2k_2 &=& 0\end{array} $$
We've now found an equation that allows us to solve for the input $m,n$ required given some desired output $(k_1, k_2)$. Notice that if we choose something like $k_1 = 1$ and $k_2 = 1$, then $7m = 4$, which does not have any integer solutions for $m$. Hence, $f$ is not surjective.

For injectivity, if $(2m_1 + n_1, 3m_1 + 5n_1) = (2m_2 + n_2, 3m_2 + 5n_2)$ for some $m_1, m_2, n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then
$$\begin{array}{c} 2m_1 + n_1 &=& 2m_2 + n_2 \\ 3m_1 + 5n_1 &=& 3m_2 + 5n_2\end{array} $$
Combining,
$$\begin{array}{c} n_1 &=& n_2 \\ m_1 &=& m_2\end{array} $$
Which shows that $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 0):

We can write $f((m,n)) = A \begin{bmatrix} m \\ n \end{bmatrix}$ for some matrix $A$. Note that
$\det A = 7$ so $A$ is invertible in the reals, hence injective in the reals, hence injective in the integers.

Note that $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix} f((m,n)) = 7 (m+n)$, hence
we have $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}f(\mathbb{Z}^2)= 7 \mathbb{Z} $.

Note that there are lots of pairs $(p,q)$ that do not satisfy
$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} p \\ q \end{bmatrix} \in 7 \mathbb{Z} $ (for example, $(1,1)$), hence $f$ is not surjective.

(In fact, using the above idea, it is not hard to show that $(p,q)$ is in the range **iff** $7 \mid 2p+q $.)